# Strapi (deployed on fly.io)) : how could I host my uploads on my own hosting?

Tags: file-upload, strapi, fly

I've managed deploying Strapi on fly.io (hobby plan).

I would like to know if it would be possible to host the medias (uploads, etc) on my own hosting (Planethoster).

Can anyone explain if it is possible and how to achieve it ?

Thanks !